# ERROR Exception Property [tratamientos] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tablas Relacion de Muchos a Muchos

**Tratamiento:** Id, descripción

**Profesional:** Id, Nombre

**Profesionales_tratamientos:** Profesional_id, Tratamiento_id

**Modelos:** Tratamiento

```
public function profesionales()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profesionales::class,'profesionales_tratamientos','tratamiento_id','profesionales_id');
}
```

Profesionales

```
public function tratamientos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tratamiento::class,'profesionales_tratamientos','profesionales_id','tratamiento_id');
}
```

Profesionales_tratamiento

**Controladores:** TratamientoController, ProfesionalController, Profesionales_tratamientoController

```
use App\Models\Profesionales;
use App\Models\Tratamiento;

public function index()
{
    $profesionales=Profesionales::with('tratamientos')->get();
    return view('Profesionales_tratamiento.index', compact('profesionales'));
}
```

**Vista:**

Profesional_tratamiento

index.balde.php

```
@foreach ($profesionales as $profesional)
<tr>  
<td>{{$profesional->apellido}}</td>

@foreach ($profesionales -> tratamientos as $tratamiento)
    
<td>{{$tratamiento->descripcion}}</td>
  
@endforeach
    
@endforeach
```

**Error:**

> Exception
> Property [tratamientos] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\citas\resources\views\Profesionales_tratamiento\index.blade.php)

Aclaro que corrí en tinker las consultas e insert y funcionaron perfectamente.

Les agradecería muchísimo...

---

Muchas gracias por responder.  Les comento que hice lo que ambos me ofrecieron y el resultado es el siguiente:
Ya no da el error, pero muestra en la primer fila el unico profesional que tengo cargado
Colaccino con sus dos tratamientos Botox y Limpieza+Hidratacion.
Pero debajo sigue mostrando todos los profesionales que tengo cargados en la base de datos. Debería sólo mostrar el cargado.
Adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edito:

Mi vista index se ve asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi edit se ve asi :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Crear se ve asi :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo funciona ok.. Pero en mi vista index es donde quiero retornar
profesional_id nombre   tratamiento_id descripcion

Los id que muestro los tengo en el controlador Profesionales_tratamiento

$profesionales_tratamiento=Profesionales_tratamiento::all();

y aca deberia meter en el array los que traigo arriba
$profesionales=Profesionales::with('tratamientos')->find([1,2,3,4]);

return view('Profesionales_tratamiento.index', compact('profesionales_tratamiento','profesionales'));

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Para poder ayudarte por favor formula mejor tu pregunta ya que no entendemos cuál es tu problema o duda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba escribiendo esto $profesionales->tratamientos;

Ponlo en la linea antes de retornar la vista.

Algo asi:

```
public function index()
{
    $profesionales=Profesionales::with('tratamientos')->get();

    foreach ($profesionales as $profesional) 
    {
        $profesional->tratamientos;
    }
    
    return view('Profesionales_tratamiento.index', compact('profesionales'));
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probé y me pasa lo que detallo en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error se genera en la siguiente línea:

```
@foreach ($profesionales -> tratamientos as $tratamiento)
```

Pero ¿por qué?

Cuando mandas la colección resultante de la consulta, la misma tendrá una clave llamada `tratamientos` dentro de cada objeto de `profesionales` que te esta devolviendo la misma.

Dicho lo anterior, entonces con el segundo foreach deberías estar iterando para acceder a los valores de las colecciones de `tratamientos` por cada objeto resultante y eso precisamente es lo que te esta haciendo falta, en cambio tratas de acceder a esos mismos valores en el *primer nivel* o lo que sería la colección de `profesionales` donde precisamente **no existen**

Entonces tu segundo `foreach` debería ser así:

```
 @foreach ($profesionales as $profesional)
  
    {{$profesional->apellido}}

    @foreach ($profesional->tratamientos as $tratamiento)
        
    {{$tratamiento->descripcion}}
    
    @endforeach
       
  @endforeach
```

**EDICIÓN**

Ahora para filtrar por determinados identificadores de profesionales, puedes modificar la consulta de esta forma:

```
$profesionales=Profesionales::with('tratamientos')->find([tus_ids_como_array]);
```

Solo toma en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Si solo usas el método `find` y alguno o varios de los ids no existen entonces solo te retornará una colección con aquellos que si fueron encontrados
- En cambio si quieres usar `findOrFail` considera que con un id que no existe vas a obtener:

  - 0 registros
  - Una excepción del tipo: **`ModelNotFoundException`**

Fuera de eso, el modo que te muestro para hacer el recorrido de valores sería el mismo

Comment: Gracias, lo probé y me pasa lo que detallo en mi respuesta.

Comment: Pero como le paso el id cargado?,  porque van a ser varios. Quiero que me traiga los tratamientos de solo los profesionales cargados en la tabla pivot.

Comment: Te agradezco infinitamente por responder., pero estoy enloqueciendo, haciendo lo que indicaste, que entiendo es:
 $profesionales=Profesionales::with('tratamientos')->find(); sin nada entre parentesis ya que quiero que traiga todos los que tenga cargados en pivot.

me da el siguiente error.

ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::find(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\citas\app\Http\Controllers\Profesionales_tratamientoController.php on line 25 and at least 1 expected

Comment: Si le agrego el array si funciona, pero si el dia de mañana el usuario da de alta un profesional y un tratamiento nuevo y carga la relacion en la tabla pivot, no va a estar en el array porque está harcodeado.  El array debería llenarse con los id de la pivot. Me explico?

Comment: Si exacto eso deberia hacer, el tema es que no se como.. soy novato en laravel y en php.. lo mio era asp.net por eso me está costando el doble.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y muestranos como llegan los ids de los profesionales que quieres usar en el filtro, por que asumo que llegan del front en el request, pero edita danos mas detalles como esos y edito la respuesta, mientras borremos comentarios y mejor amplia tu pregunta @JuanManuelFerrero

Comment: edité la original, no se si lo hice bien. Espero que me ayudes
Gracias